# Overload the subscript operator to call a function based on the type assigned

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I have an object that has functions like `addString` and `addInteger`. These functions add data to a JSON string. At the end, the JSON string can be obtained and sent out. How can this be made easier by overloading subscript operators to do the following?

```
jsonBuilder builder();

builder[ "string_value" ] = "Hello";
builder[ "int_value" ] = 5;
builder[ "another_string" ] = "Thank you";
```

Comment: Right now we're looking at `jsonBuilder::operator[]( std::string & )`. No overloading involved. How do you *want* this to be "made easier"? Do you know how overloading works? What have you tried? **What is your question?** And no, we won't code your solution for you. (I hope no-one does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a *proxy* class that is returned by the `operator[]` function and which handles the assignment. The proxy class then overloads the assignment operator to handle strings and integers differently.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct TheMainClass
{
    struct AssignmentProxy
    {
        std::string name;
        TheMainClass* main;

        AssignmentProxy(std::string const& n, TheMainClass* m)
            : name(n), main(m)
        {}

        TheMainClass& operator=(std::string const& s)
        {
            main->addString(name, s);
            return *main;
        }

        TheMainClass& operator=(int i)
        {
            main->addInteger(name, i);
            return *main;
        }
    };

    AssignmentProxy operator[](std::string const& name)
    {
        return AssignmentProxy(name, this);
    }

    void addString(std::string const& name, std::string const& str)
    {
        std::cout << "Adding string " << name << " with value \"" << str << "\"\n";
    }

    void addInteger(std::string const& name, int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Adding integer " << name << " with value " << i << "\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc __attribute__((unused)), char *argv[] __attribute__((unused)))
{
    TheMainClass builder;
    builder[ "string_value" ] = "Hello";
    builder[ "int_value" ] = 5;
    builder[ "another_string" ] = "Thank you";
}
```

[See here for a working example.](http://ideone.com/HSSAni)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this finally. I have implemented for getting the string input, do the same for integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class jsonBuilder
{
    public:
        std::map<std::string,std::string> json_container;
        std::string&  operator[](char *inp)
        {
            std::string value;
            json_container[std::string(inp)];
            std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator iter=json_container.find(std::string(inp));

            return iter->second;            
        }   
};

int main()
{
    jsonBuilder jb;
    jb["a"]="b";

    std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator iter=jb.json_container.find(std::string("a"));
    std::cout<<"output: "<<iter->second;
}
```